# Codeigniter Email REGEX

Tags: regex, codeigniter

What is the regular expression used by codeigniter to validate email addresses? I plan on using the same regex on the javascript part of the form validation, so that the regexes won't collide, e.g. xy#@spic7.com might pass in the javascript part, but it won't pass in the php part )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have looked at the source code yourself in the same amount of time it took to post this question but, either way, this is the method CI uses to validate emails, straight from `system/libraries/Form_validation.php`:

```
/**
 * Valid Email
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string
 * @return  bool
 */
function valid_email($str)
{
    return ( ! preg_match("/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, my head was just going to explode just now, I was debugging for a few hours straight, and it results in my mind being unable to think clearly now and just looking for shortcuts :p

Comment: I'll be sure to check out the source code myself next time lol

Comment: @SpaceLaying: No problem - I think we've all been in those situations before!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best solution is calling email helper and checking email validity:

```
$this->load->helper('email');

if (valid_email('email@somesite.com')) echo 'email is valid';
```